# What's the expected value of working modules?

Tags: probability

> An electric system is made up of $k$ modules. In each module, there are $N$ resistors in series. What is the expected value of working modules if $m$ resistor break down? A module is not working if there is at least $1$ bad resistor in it.
> [image]

I can calculate the trivial cases (for example, $m=1$, or $m>(k-1)*N$), but I can't find out the general solution.

For $m\leq N$, I think I can use the binomial distribution: The probability for a module to have $n$ bad resistor is $$p(n)=\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N-n}$$
and we would need to sum up this probability to cover all of the possible cases and multiple them with $1, 2, \dots N$ to get the expected value, but it seems to be a really big sum.

**Bounty:** I'd really like to have a solution to this problem, so I started a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability the first module has no bad resistors is the probability the $m$ bad resistors are in the other $k-1$ modules which by a counting argument is $\dfrac{{N(k-1) \choose m}}{{Nk \choose m}}$ - and you can take this to be $0$ if $m \gt N(k-1)$

So the expected number of working modules is  $$k\dfrac{{N(k-1) \choose m}}{{Nk \choose m}}$$

Comment: It might be trivial, but why is the expected value is the product of the number of the modules and the probability of 1 working module?

Comment: @Botond strictly speaking the expected number of *first modules* working is the probability it is working and similarly the expected number of *second modules* working and so on, so the same expression, and the final result is then the sum of $k$ copies of $\frac{{N(k-1) \choose m}}{{Nk \choose m}}$, one copy for each module, by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity)

Comment: Thank you, I think I start to understand it, but I will need a bit more time to understand it completely.